# Why do I get an error on the last line of installing Pylons 1.0 with easy_install and Python 2.7 in Windows Vista 64?

Tags: python, windows, installation, pylons, easy-install

I tried to install **Pylons 1.0** with **Python 2.7** using the `easy_install` command in **Windows Vista 64** but got the error:

```
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']
```

Here is the link to the whole installation process from command prompt
http://pastie.org/1190341

- Why do I get this error?
- How do I solve it?
- Will Pylons work even though I got this error?

Comment: I know it's not a real answer, but switch to linux, your host is running it anyway and you won't have these headaches. I deal with windows 7 64 bit issues constantly and when it comes to ruby, python, java.... hell anything development related with web apps: unless you are tied to .NET in some preternatural courtship, kill windows, linux is free. and +1 for using pylons.

Answer (score 6):

From the error:

```
File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in q
uery_vcvarsall
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']
```

distutils looks for a file called vcvarsall.bat. It runs it and gets the include and lib directories that the batch file sets up. The batch file sets up the environment based on what platform you supply to it.

vcvarsall.bat should be in a directory like: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC

Create following directories:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvarsamd64.bat

in vcvarsamd64.bat

call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /x64 /Release

All these above sets up windows tool chain to work with disutils. While you may have 64 bit python, most packages on pypi comes with 32 bit precompiled binaries. disutils needs to use your compiler tool chain for building 64 bit extensions. This is where all this come into picture.

Please look at :

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/12/30/using-different-toolsets-for-vc-build.aspx

What vcvarsamd64.bat and other batchfile does is setup up paths for libs, tools etc which can be used by disutils.

[Edit: setenv.cmd not found in v6]

https://serverfault.com/questions/114998/vista-cmd-shell-thinks-its-windows-server-2008-debug

Comment: I created the 2 directories but I do not understand what you mean by your last line: call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /x64 /Release ?

Comment: @pyfunc thanks for explaining why I need to take this step. I am still confused as to what I need to do. I did go to the link and saw that Olga mentioned the same path that you did but she also says stuff about setting INCLUDE, LIB, LIBPATH and PATH environment variables to point to the corresponding directories of the toolset you want to use. She basically lost me there. Do I have to do any of that? What do I place inside of the vcvarsamd64.bat directory? A file?

Comment: @J3M 7OR3: Thats the job of SetEnv.cmd which comes as a part of MS SDK. Look for it or search for Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Vista. Just add that in the batch file and this will set up all that for you.

Comment: @pyfunc Ahh. I understand. The problem is that I do not have a v7.1 dir, only a v6.0A dir. And with in the Bin in the v6.0A dir I have no SetEnv.cmd command that I can run. Should I download the latest SDK form here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx or could that screw with my system?

Comment: @J3M 7OR3: Ah, v7.1 dir is for windows 7. I think you should do find it some where. Please look at this SO discussion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887894/how-to-find-windows-sdks-setenv-cmd-setenv-cmd-does-not-work-correctly

Comment: @J3M 7OR3: Also can you try searching for SetEnv.* in the SDK directory

Comment: @pyfunc ok I searched C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin and I could not find SetEnv.cmd anywhere. Here are all the files I found http://pastie.org/1191341 Also when I try to find SetEnv.cmd by running 'where *.cmd" I get this http://pastie.org/1191352 and SetEnv.cmd is not there. So if I can not even locate it should I download it? If so which version/package?

Comment: @pyfunc I looked at the server fault question and followed the instructions by @Jason to search for 'cmd' by going Start > Search. One cmd.exe appears in the search list. He doesn't say what to do next though. Also I should mention that I have Microsoft Visual c++ 2008 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 installed. Each of those have their own cmd.exe. Open Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt and Open Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010). When I use any of those as well as well as my regular cmd.exe I can not locate SetEnv.cmd. There has got to be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's a workaround mentioned on pylons discuss list:

- [simplejson workaround for Pylons 0.9.7 on Windows, Python 2.6](http://markmail.org/message/ppd6wcdim5lxcgc4)

It's a bit old (2008), but since your pasted output shows failure on compiling simplejson, it seems relevant.  You might try following the suggestions there to see if it helps.

Comment: I got to the point where it says to download setuptools and then when I ran the installer for 2.7 it says that I need Python 2.7 but it can not find it in the registry. Very confusing because I have Python 2.7. Not sure what it means by registry. I also have Python 2.6 installed. Don't know if that is getting in the way or not.

Comment: @J3M: from your question and pasted output, it seems you already have Python 2.7, setuptools/easy_install.  So you don't need to follow those steps.  Just steps 4 and 5 to get going with mingw should be sufficient.

Comment: well I did it and SimpleJSON got installed but I still got the same error. @pyfunc seems to know what they are talking about with getting disutils to use my compiler tool chain to build the needed 64 bit extensions. If this doesn't work out I am just going to switch to my Linux distro and bag Windows all together for dev purposes.

Answer (score 2):

if you have installed x64 visual studio you can use the cmd tool in the visual studio tools in the start menu. It will set up the environment for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you couldn't build a C extension, something that is often difficult for Windows users.  Try to find a Windows kit for Pylons.  Or, look for help on installing MinGW so you can build the extensions.

Comment: what is a Windows kit for Pylons? By the way, I followed the instructions using the Pylons book.

Comment: Also, once I have installed MinGW how do I build the extension? Is it just a matter of reinstalling Pylons after I have installed MinGW?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a huge amount of time trying to get the c++ compiler to work with 64 bit Python on 64 bit Windows. It turns out the answer was here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246588(v=vs.90).aspx

Run the VS 2008 Professional installer again and make sure make sure "X64 Compilers and Tools" is selected in the installer options.