# How come Pylons is not recognized when I run 'import pylons' in Windows Vista command prompt?

Tags: python, windows, installation, pylons

When I try to import pylons in the virtual python environment I get the error

```
C:\env\Scripts>python
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (A
MD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more informati
on.
>>> import pylons
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\pylons-1.0-py2.7.egg\pylons\__init
__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from paste.registry import StackedObjectProxy
ImportError: No module named registry
```

As I understand this error, Python is telling me that it can not find the module named **registry**. Perhaps this is a result of the error I got while installing Pylons which is explained over here  [Why do I get an error on the last line of installing Pylons 1.0 with easy_install and Python 2.7 in Windows Vista 64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827170/why-do-i-get-an-error-on-the-last-line-of-installing-pylons-1-0-with-easy-install)

It seems that many of the Pylon components were installed but I guess **registry** was not or maybe Pylons just can not see it.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you certain that the version of Pylons you installed is 1. compatible with Vista, 2. compatible with Python 2.7, and 3. compatible with the 64-bit version of Python 2.7? Most non-standard libraries or extensions are not compatible with Python for AMD 64.

Comment: I am certain I installed Pylons 1.0. As far as it being compatiable with Vista and AMD64 I figure the author's of Pylons would have mentioned something about that at the Pylon's site http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/1.0/gettingstarted/#requirements .There it says "Python 2 series above and including 2.4 (Python 3 or later not supported at
this time)". Now I am really confused. Are you saying that I have to install Python 32 bit?

Comment: I realize that what I need to be able to do is to get Python's disutils to access my compiler tool chain in order to build the necessary 64 bit extensions. I am still trying to figure out how to do this. Getting closer with the help of @pyfunc over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827170/why-do-i-get-an-error-on-the-last-line-of-installing-pylons-1-0-with-easy-install

Comment: Try it with the 32-bit version of Python. Even though I have a 64-bit machine and OS, I use the 32-bit version because the 64-bit version creates incompatibilities.

Comment: would i have this problem if I used 64 bit python on a Linux distro? or is this just windows related? thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You have to activate the virtual environment before you can import pylons.

```
C:\Users\Josh>env\scripts\activate
(env) C:\Users\Josh>python
ActivePython 2.6.2.2 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Apr 21 2009, 15:05:37) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pylons
>>>
```

vs. this

```
C:\Users\Josh\env\Scripts>python
ActivePython 2.6.2.2 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Apr 21 2009, 15:05:37) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> pylons
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pylons' is not defined
>>>
```

I guessing that you have the pylons package installed outside and inside your virtual environment. So python is letting you import pylons but the paste package is not installed outside of your virtual environment so you are getting an error.

Running the *activate* batch script (should be inside your env\Scripts folder) should solve the problem.