# How do I run msbuild from the command line using Windows SDK 7.1?

Tags: .net-4.0, msbuild, sdk

I'm setting up .NET 4.0 support on our CI server. I've installed .NET 4.0, and the .NET tools from the Windows 7.1 SDK.

On .NET 2.0 and 3.5, that just worked. With .NET 4, when I run the "Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt" from the Start menu, it complains about

```
The x86 compilers are not currently installed. x86-x86
Please go to Add/Remove Programs to update your installation.
.
Setting SDK environment relative to C:\Program Files\Microsoft
SDKs\Windows\v7.1
\.
Targeting Windows Server 2008 x86 Debug
```

Then when I try to run msbuild, I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1>msbuild
'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1>
```

I can't quite believe that installing the runtime and SDK will leave you with a system that can't run msbuild... have I missed some obvious step or obscure Windows Update, or is time to give up and start hacking the system path?

Comment: What is MS Build trying to build? If it's a C++ project, make sure the x86 compilers are installed. If you CI server is Server Core, make sure you install WOW64 (Though I've had no success running CI on Server Core)

Comment: Nope - plain .NET 4.0 web apps on a Windows Server 2008 SP1...

Comment: Erm, so you can't quite belief that you can configure a build server without paying the license fee?  The VS license allows you to install on more than one machine.  I'd recommend you take advantage of that.

Comment: What is the `%VCTools%` environment variable set to? It should be set to a path. Does `cl.exe` exist in that path? Also, are you on a non-English Windows? I've heard some reports of this problem on localized Windows installation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887894/how-to-find-windows-sdks-setenv-cmd-setenv-cmd-does-not-work-correctly

Answer (score 407, accepted):

To enable `msbuild` in **Command Prompt**, you simply have to add the directory of the `msbuild.exe` install on your machine to the `PATH` environment variable.

You can access the environment variables by:

1. Right clicking on **Computer**
2. Click **Properties**
3. Then click **Advanced system settings** on the left navigation bar
4. On the next dialog box click **Environment variables**
5. Scroll down to `PATH`
6. Edit it to include your path to the framework (don't forget a "**;**" after the last entry in here).

For reference, my path was `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`

## Path Updates:

As of MSBuild 12 (2013)/VS 2013/.NET 4.5.1+ and onward [MSBuild is now installed as a part of Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2013/07/24/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio/).

For **VS2015** the path was `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\Bin`

For **VS2017** the path was `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\<YOUR_VS_EDITION>\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`

For **VS2019** the path was `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\<YOUR_VS_EDITION>\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

For **VS2022** the path was `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\<YOUR_VS_EDITION>\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

where `<YOUR_VS_EDITION>` matches the Visual Studio edition that you have installed, i.e., `Preview`, `Community`, `Professional`, `Enterprise`.

Comment: I do this as well to make msbuild always available in PowerShell

Comment: Just remember to restart the Prompt after add the new path.

Comment: Also, you can't have any white space after the ';' character.

Comment: That is the old directory, MSBuild doesn't install with .NET framework, actually even at the time of question it was deprecated info. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh162058.aspx

Comment: I found this pretty helpful if you don't know where the path to `MSBuild` is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15446618/198348

Comment: Base on the article above the correct path to add to environment variables for me was `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\msbuild\14.0\Bin`

Comment: The path has changed for MSBuild 15.0. It's now under the VisualStudio 2017 install directory. For example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`. 
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/what-s-new-in-msbuild-15-0

Comment: It appears to have changed again in Visual Studio 2019. The path on my machine is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin`.

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`I tried the above and it didn't work for me I am using VS Express 2015 and VS Code 1.54.1

Comment: If you are using the VS install of MSBuild make sure you match your edition in the PATH (Community, Professional, Enterprise)

Comment: @ShariqueKhan Currently facing the same problem with VS Express 2015. Did you manage to get this solved?

Comment: @YouJin yes it was resolved by adding the correct path.

Comment: Path after installation of build tools only: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

Answer (score 75):

From `Visual Studio 2013` onwards, `MSbuild` comes as a part of Visual Studio. Earlier, MSBuild was installed as a part of. NET Framework.

**MSBuild** is installed directly under **%ProgramFiles%**. So, the path for MSBuild might be different depending on the version of Visual Studio.

For `Visual Studio 2015`, Path of `MSBuild` is `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"`

For `Visual Studio 15 Preview`, Path of `MSBuild` is `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"`

Also, Some new MSBuild properties has been added and some have been modified.
For more information look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh162058(v=vs.140).aspx)

**Update 1: VS 2017**

The location for the MSBuild has changed again with the release of **Visual Studio 2017**. Now the installation directory is under the `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\[VS Edition]\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\`. Since, i have an Enterprise edition, the MSBuild location for my machine is `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSbuild.exe"`

**Update 2: VS 2019**

Path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MsBuild.exe`.

Answer (score 15):

**Using the "Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 20XX" shortcut** instead of "cmd" will set the path for msbuild automatically without having to add it to your environment variables.

Comment: No, it doesn't (at least not in environment where only msbuild is installed, but not visual studio)

Comment: @Ezh if Visual Studio 20XX is not installed, there won't be a "Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 20XX" shortcut.

Answer (score 6):

Your bat file could be like:

```
CD C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

msbuild C:\Users\mmaratt\Desktop\BladeTortoise\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj

PAUSE

EXIT
```

Comment: Giving the full path to msbuild means you can look for a project file in the current directory, instead of hard-coding it. Something like `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild *.*proj` might do it, although do note that the path for newer versions  of MSBuild (circa 2013) is different.

Comment: That path still exists in 2022 and always the same despite you VS version, but it cannot build .net core projects. sad.

Answer (score 6):

For Visual Studio 2019 (Preview, at least) it is now in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe

I imagine the process will be similar for the official 2019 release.

Comment: Correct. In Visual Studio 2019 the path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MsBuild.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to build with C# 6 syntax use this in path:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2022 (Preview, at least) it is now in:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Current

I imagine the process will be similar for the official 2022 release.

Comment: Yes, it is this path now.

Answer (score 1):

For visual studio 2022 you should add this to your "environment variables":

%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin

if you have not this path in your windows, find similar path by searching your %ProgramFiles% directory

Answer (score 0):

you can add msbuild path as follows in system variables.

[image]

Now open a new command prompt or powershell. Type below command.

```
msbuild /version
```

if version is displayed your environment setting is good.

Answer (score -4):

The **`SetEnv.cmd` script that the "SDK command prompt" shortcut installed with Windows SDK 7.1 erroneously runs checks for `cl.exe`** in various places before adding any entries to `PATH`. So it fails to add anything if a native C compiler is not installed, even if .NET tools are.

**A workaround is to run the Windows SDK 7.1 installer and install the SDK's native C++ toolchain, too.**

**A real fix is to apply the below patch to `SetEnv.cmd`**

It resides under `<SDK install dir>\Bin\SetEnv.cmd`. This will also fix missing paths to other tools located in `<SDK install dir>\Bin` and subfolders.

```patch
--- SetEnv.Cmd_ 2010-04-27 19:52:00.000000000 +0400
+++ SetEnv.Cmd  2013-12-02 15:05:30.834400000 +0400
@@ -228,10 +228,10 @@
 
 IF "%CURRENT_CPU%" =="x64" (
   IF "%TARGET_CPU%" == "x64" (
+    SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir64%\%FrameworkVersion%;%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
+    SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\x64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
     IF EXIST "%VCTools%\amd64\cl.exe" (
       SET "VCTools=%VCTools%\amd64;%VCTools%\VCPackages;"
-      SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\x64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
-      SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir64%\%FrameworkVersion%;%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
     ) ELSE (
       SET VCTools=
       ECHO The x64 compilers are not currently installed.
@@ -239,10 +239,10 @@
       ECHO .
     )
   ) ELSE IF "%TARGET_CPU%" == "IA64" (
+    SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir64%\%FrameworkVersion%;%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
+    SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\x64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
     IF EXIST "%VCTools%\x86_ia64\cl.exe" (
       SET "VCTools=%VCTools%\x86_ia64;%VCTools%\VCPackages;"
-      SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\x64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
-      SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir64%\%FrameworkVersion%;%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
     ) ELSE (
       SET VCTools=
       ECHO The IA64 compilers are not currently installed.
@@ -250,10 +250,10 @@
       ECHO .
     )
   ) ELSE IF "%TARGET_CPU%" == "x86" (
+    SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
+    SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
     IF EXIST "%VCTools%\cl.exe" (
       SET "VCTools=%VCTools%;%VCTools%\VCPackages;"
-      SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
-      SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
     ) ELSE (
       SET VCTools=
       ECHO The x86 compilers are not currently installed.
@@ -263,10 +263,10 @@
   )
 ) ELSE IF "%CURRENT_CPU%" =="IA64" (
   IF "%TARGET_CPU%" == "IA64" (
+    SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir64%\%FrameworkVersion%;%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
+    SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\IA64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\IA64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
     IF EXIST "%VCTools%\IA64\cl.exe" (
       SET "VCTools=%VCTools%\IA64;%VCTools%;%VCTools%\VCPackages;"
-      SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\IA64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\IA64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
-      SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir64%\%FrameworkVersion%;%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
     ) ELSE (
       SET VCTools=
       ECHO The IA64 compilers are not currently installed.
@@ -274,10 +274,10 @@
       ECHO .
     )
   ) ELSE IF "%TARGET_CPU%" == "x64" (
+    SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir64%\%FrameworkVersion%;%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
+    SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\IA64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\IA64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
     IF EXIST "%VCTools%\x86_amd64\cl.exe" (
       SET "VCTools=%VCTools%\x86_amd64;%VCTools%\VCPackages;"
-      SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\IA64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\IA64;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
-      SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir64%\%FrameworkVersion%;%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
     ) ELSE (
       SET VCTools=
       ECHO The VC compilers are not currently installed.
@@ -285,10 +285,10 @@
       ECHO .
     )
   ) ELSE IF "%TARGET_CPU%" == "x86" (
+    SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
+    SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
     IF EXIST "%VCTools%\cl.exe" (
       SET "VCTools=%VCTools%;%VCTools%\VCPackages;"
-      SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
-      SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
     ) ELSE (
       SET VCTools=
       ECHO The x86 compilers are not currently installed.
@@ -298,10 +298,10 @@
   )
 ) ELSE IF "%CURRENT_CPU%"=="x86" (
   IF "%TARGET_CPU%" == "x64" (
+    SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
+    SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
     IF EXIST "%VCTools%\x86_amd64\cl.exe" (
       SET "VCTools=%VCTools%\x86_amd64;%VCTools%\VCPackages;"
-      SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
-      SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
     ) ELSE (
       SET VCTools=
       ECHO The x64 cross compilers are not currently installed.
@@ -309,10 +309,10 @@
       ECHO .
     )
   ) ELSE IF "%TARGET_CPU%" == "IA64" (
+    SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
+    SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
     IF EXIST "%VCTools%\x86_IA64\cl.exe" (
       SET "VCTools=%VCTools%\x86_IA64;%VCTools%;%VCTools%\VCPackages;"
-      SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
-      SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
     ) ELSE (
       SET VCTools=
       ECHO The IA64 compilers are not currently installed.
@@ -320,10 +320,10 @@
       ECHO .
     )
   ) ELSE IF "%TARGET_CPU%" == "x86" (
+    SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
+    SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
     IF EXIST "%VCTools%\cl.exe" (
       SET "VCTools=%VCTools%;%VCTools%\VCPackages;"
-      SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
-      SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
     ) ELSE (
       SET VCTools=
       ECHO The x86 compilers are not currently installed. x86-x86
@@ -331,15 +331,17 @@
       ECHO .
     )
   )
-) ELSE IF EXIST "%VCTools%\cl.exe" (
-  SET "VCTools=%VCTools%;%VCTools%\VCPackages;"
-  SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
-  SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
 ) ELSE (
-  SET VCTools=
-  ECHO The x86 compilers are not currently installed. default
-  ECHO Please go to Add/Remove Programs to update your installation.
-  ECHO .
+  SET "FxTools=%FrameworkDir32%%FrameworkVersion%;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;"
+  SET "SdkTools=%WindowsSdkDir%Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;"
+  IF EXIST "%VCTools%\cl.exe" (
+    SET "VCTools=%VCTools%;%VCTools%\VCPackages;"
+  ) ELSE (
+    SET VCTools=
+    ECHO The x86 compilers are not currently installed. default
+    ECHO Please go to Add/Remove Programs to update your installation.
+    ECHO .
+  )
 )
 
 :: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The most creaziest and complicated solution I ever saw in my life :-)))

Comment: @ADM-IT Wecome to the wonderful world of downstream patching.