# Unknown option: \ %{SetTimeOfDayColors()}

Tags: function, vim, color-scheme

Here is my `.vimrc` config file according to the book `<<learning the vi and vim>>` `p201-203`.

```
function SetTimeOfDayColors()
    let currentHour = strftime("%H")
    if currentHour < 6 + 0
            let colorScheme = "darkblue"
        elseif currentHour < 12 + 0
        let colorScheme = "morning"
    elseif currentHour < 18 + 0
        let colorScheme = "shine"
    else
        let colorScheme = "evening"
    endif
    echo  "setting color scheme to " . colorScheme
    execute  "colorscheme " . colorScheme
endfunction
set statusline += \ %{SetTimeOfDayColors()}
```

An error occur when to `vim test.txt`.

> line   15: E518: Unknown option: \ %{SetTimeOfDayColors()} Press ENTER
>   or type command to continue

What is the matter with the codes here?

Comment: just remove the space after the `+=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not use whitespace around the `=` (or `+=`) assignment of `:set`:

```
set statusline+=\ %{SetTimeOfDayColors()}
```

You've properly escaped the leading space, though. Here, this is easy to fix; for more complicated modifications, it can be useful to switch to `:let` instead:

```
let &statusline .= ' %{SetTimeOfDayColors()}'
```

As `:let` deals with variables (and the `&statusline` is a special case referring to an option), you can have whitespace here, and do not need to escape whitespace, because the right-hand side is an expression (here: a quoted string).