# How to compile with Visual Studio x64?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit

I would like to compile in VS2008 x64 from bat file.

When I compile in VS2008 32 bits I call vsvars32.bat.

What do I need to call to compile in x64?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nowadays the recommendation is not to use `vsvar32.bat` and use `SetEnv.cmd` instead to set up your build environment. Pass the `/x64` argument to select a 64 bit build environment. This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660764.aspx) has some more information about `SetEnv.cmd`.

Comment: I don't think this actually correct - if you look at the shortcut for VS2015 command prompt, it points to the vcvarsall.bat file.  SetEnv.cmd is intended for a different job - creating a command line development environment, not setting up the command line for working with VS (as vsvars.bat file did)

Comment: I don't think there's any contradiction here

Comment: From the docs: "[you can use] SetEnv utility to configure your application build settings."  Eg - you set /Debug or /Release options.  The vcvarsall simply sets up paths to allow Visual Studio to find itself, it does not carry any sort of implication on project-specific settings.  The documentation also states that vsvars32 is the equivalent of "vcvarsall x86"

Comment: also, searching my install of VS2015, I don't find the SetEnv utility :)

Comment: It's part of the compiler toolset rather than the IDE toolset

Comment: I've never used it SetEnv.cmd, but I understand it's part of the Windows SDK, (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887894/how-to-find-windows-sdks-setenv-cmd-setenv-cmd-does-not-work-correctly)

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to go in the directory : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64" and execute the file : "vcvarsamd64.bat"

Answer (score 1):

You need to install "X64 Compilers and Tools" feature in your VS2008 IDE.

Please try adding "X64 Compilers and Tools" feature via Control Panel >> Add/Remove Programs (For Vista or later OS, please go to "Programs and Features").
After entering Visual Studio 2008 Maintenance Mode, please expand "Visual C++" node >> click "X64 Compilers and Tools" >> click "Update" button.

Then you can enter "Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt (x64)"

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio will install shortcuts to launch command prompts that setup an appropriate environment for triggering builds.  You can see where the shortcut for the x64 Command Prompt points to by right clicking on it and checking out its target property.  It typically points to:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64

There is more information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s.aspx

Comment: Question asks specifically about VS2008 rather than 2015

Comment: No, it asks what is equivalent to vsvars32.bat.  Jerome B's answer is probably the closest, I added this answer as it describes how to discover the location (not everyone installs to C:)

Comment: from MSDN: "calling vsvars32 is the equivalent of calling vcvarsall x86" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx

Comment: please remove your downvote, as I reworded the answer to be general to all versions of VS