# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment - .EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

This error appears when I try to load a JNI C/C++ dll library, and I noticed it says "The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code." Not sure what that means? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Java-Source code follows:

```
package demojni;
public class Main {
   static {
      System.load("C:\\Users\\Nicholas1\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\DemoJNI_Lib\\dist\\DemoJNI_Lib.dll"); // Load native library at runtime
                                   // hello.dll (Windows) or libhello.so (Unixes)
   }

   // Declare a native method sayHello() that receives nothing and returns void


   // Test Driver
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Main().sayHelloWorld();  // invoke the native method
   }
   private native void sayHelloWorld();
}
```

C-Source code follows:

```
#include "DemoJNI_Lib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_demojni_Main_sayHelloWorld
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj){
    printf("Hello World \n");
}
```

JNI C-header-Source code follows:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class demojni_Main */

#ifndef _Included_demojni_Main
#define _Included_demojni_Main
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     demojni_Main
 * Method:    sayHelloWorld
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_demojni_Main_sayHelloWorld
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Error when I run Main.java file:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000002c2ed90, pid=7552, tid=0x0000000000001e2c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b14) (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000002c2ed90
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Nicholas1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DemoJNI\hs_err_pid7552.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
C:\Users\Nicholas1\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 27 seconds)
```

Error Log (hs_err_pid7552.log):

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000002c2ed90, pid=7552, tid=0x0000000000001e2c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b14) (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000002c2ed90
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000013dd800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=7724, stack(0x0000000002b30000,0x0000000002c30000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, ExceptionInformation=0x0000000000000008 0x0000000002c2ed90

Registers:
RAX=0x000000000000000a, RBX=0x0000000014de0360, RCX=0x00000001802e4ae0, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x0000000002c2f140, RBP=0x0000000002c2f160, RSI=0x0000000020200021, RDI=0x00000000ffffffff
R8 =0x0000000002c2f0dc, R9 =0x000000018013c900, R10=0x0000000002c30000, R11=0x0000000002c2ed90
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000014de0360, R14=0x0000000002c2f1f8, R15=0x00000000013dd800
RIP=0x0000000002c2ed90, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010247

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000002c2f140)
0x0000000002c2f140:   0000000002c2f400 00000000013dd800
0x0000000002c2f150:   0000000014de0360 0000000020200021
0x0000000002c2f160:   0000000002c2f1d8 0000000002d97f74
0x0000000002c2f170:   00000000013dd9f8 0000000002c2f1f8
0x0000000002c2f180:   0000000020200021 00000000013dd800
0x0000000002c2f190:   0000000002d97ca2 0000000002c2f198
0x0000000002c2f1a0:   0000000014de0360 0000000002c2f1f8
0x0000000002c2f1b0:   0000000014de0460 0000000000000000
0x0000000002c2f1c0:   0000000014de0360 0000000000000000
0x0000000002c2f1d0:   0000000002c2f1f8 0000000002c2f240
0x0000000002c2f1e0:   0000000002d8835d 0000000000000000
0x0000000002c2f1f0:   0000000002d919d8 00000000eb26c8f8
0x0000000002c2f200:   0000000002c2f200 0000000014de02bf
0x0000000002c2f210:   0000000002c2f250 0000000014de0460
0x0000000002c2f220:   0000000000000000 0000000014de02d8
0x0000000002c2f230:   0000000002c2f1f8 0000000002c2f250 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000002c2ed90)
0x0000000002c2ed70:   1e 00 1f 00 00 00 00 00 1d fc 1e 80 01 00 00 00
0x0000000002c2ed80:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cb 17 2a 47 f8 7f 00 00
0x0000000002c2ed90:   00 d8 3d 01 00 00 00 00 f8 f1 c2 02 00 00 00 00
0x0000000002c2eda0:   60 03 de 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000000000000a is an unknown value
RBX={method} {0x0000000014de0368} 'sayHelloWorld' '()V' in 'demojni/Main'
RCX=0x00000001802e4ae0 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x0000000002c2f140 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000013dd800
RBP=0x0000000002c2f160 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000013dd800
RSI=0x0000000020200021 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000000ffffffff is an unallocated location in the heap
R8 =0x0000000002c2f0dc is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000013dd800
R9 =0x000000018013c900 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000002c30000 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000013dd800
R11=0x0000000002c2ed90 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000013dd800
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13={method} {0x0000000014de0368} 'sayHelloWorld' '()V' in 'demojni/Main'
R14=0x0000000002c2f1f8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000013dd800
R15=0x00000000013dd800 is a thread


Stack: [0x0000000002b30000,0x0000000002c30000],  sp=0x0000000002c2f140,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x0000000002c2ed90

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  demojni.Main.sayHelloWorld()V+0
j  demojni.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+7
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00000000153de000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6960, stack(0x0000000017200000,0x0000000017300000)]
  0x000000001538c000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5380, stack(0x0000000016d00000,0x0000000016e00000)]
  0x0000000015383000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10140, stack(0x0000000016c00000,0x0000000016d00000)]
  0x000000001537d800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6316, stack(0x0000000016b00000,0x0000000016c00000)]
  0x000000001537c000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10072, stack(0x0000000016a00000,0x0000000016b00000)]
  0x000000001537a800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5612, stack(0x0000000016900000,0x0000000016a00000)]
  0x000000001536a800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6568, stack(0x00000000165f0000,0x00000000166f0000)]
  0x0000000002d6f000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9964, stack(0x00000000164f0000,0x00000000165f0000)]
=>0x00000000013dd800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=7724, stack(0x0000000002b30000,0x0000000002c30000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000015346800 VMThread [stack: 0x00000000163f0000,0x00000000164f0000] [id=7392]
  0x0000000016e48000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000017300000,0x0000000017400000] [id=9832]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 983K [0x00000000eb200000, 0x00000000ec700000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 16384K, 6% used [0x00000000eb200000,0x00000000eb2f5c90,0x00000000ec200000)
  from space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ec480000,0x00000000ec480000,0x00000000ec700000)
  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ec200000,0x00000000ec200000,0x00000000ec480000)
 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 0K [0x00000000c1600000, 0x00000000c4100000, 0x00000000eb200000)
  object space 44032K, 0% used [0x00000000c1600000,0x00000000c1600000,0x00000000c4100000)
 Metaspace       used 2593K, capacity 4486K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 282K, capacity 386K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000012140000,0x0000000012340000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011b35000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x00000000774aa6c0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012890000, 0x0000000013838000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000013838000, 0x00000000147e0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000001210000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1104Kb max_used=1105Kb free=244655Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002d80000, 0x0000000002ff0000, 0x0000000011d80000]
 total_blobs=255 nmethods=24 adapters=145
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.123 Thread 0x000000001538c000   20  s    3       java.lang.StringBuffer::append (13 bytes)
Event: 0.124 Thread 0x0000000015383000   22       4       java.lang.String::charAt (29 bytes)
Event: 0.124 Thread 0x000000001538c000 nmethod 20 0x0000000002e90510 code [0x0000000002e906c0, 0x0000000002e90dd8]
Event: 0.124 Thread 0x000000001538c000   21       3       java.lang.String::equals (81 bytes)
Event: 0.125 Thread 0x000000001538c000 nmethod 21 0x0000000002e91190 code [0x0000000002e91320, 0x0000000002e91870]
Event: 0.125 Thread 0x000000001538c000   23       3       java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder::append (50 bytes)
Event: 0.125 Thread 0x0000000015383000 nmethod 22 0x0000000002e94710 code [0x0000000002e94860, 0x0000000002e94918]
Event: 0.126 Thread 0x000000001538c000 nmethod 23 0x0000000002e93ad0 code [0x0000000002e93ca0, 0x0000000002e943f8]
Event: 0.126 Thread 0x000000001538c000   24       3       java.util.Arrays::copyOfRange (63 bytes)
Event: 0.127 Thread 0x000000001538c000 nmethod 24 0x0000000002e92850 code [0x0000000002e92a60, 0x0000000002e93598]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (2 events):
Event: 0.050 Thread 0x00000000013dd800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x00000000eb207c78) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\
Event: 0.050 Thread 0x00000000013dd800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x00000000eb207f60) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.275 loading class java/security/BasicPermissionCollection
Event: 0.275 loading class java/security/BasicPermissionCollection done
Event: 0.276 loading class sun/launcher/LauncherHelper$FXHelper
Event: 0.276 loading class sun/launcher/LauncherHelper$FXHelper done
Event: 0.276 loading class java/lang/Class$MethodArray
Event: 0.276 loading class java/lang/Class$MethodArray done
Event: 0.276 loading class java/lang/Void
Event: 0.276 loading class java/lang/Void done
Event: 4.121 Executing VM operation: EnableBiasedLocking
Event: 4.121 Executing VM operation: EnableBiasedLocking done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff6ddee0000 - 0x00007ff6ddf17000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe
0x00007ff84a010000 - 0x00007ff84a1bc000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ff849bf0000 - 0x00007ff849d2e000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ff8472a0000 - 0x00007ff8473b5000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ff845af0000 - 0x00007ff845b7e000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x00007ff822700000 - 0x00007ff822753000     C:\Windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcGenral.DLL
0x00007ff849b40000 - 0x00007ff849bea000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ff846f40000 - 0x00007ff846f6e000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
0x00007ff8478a0000 - 0x00007ff8478f4000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x00007ff847b00000 - 0x00007ff847c77000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x00007ff8499a0000 - 0x00007ff849b34000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x00007ff848020000 - 0x00007ff849539000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ff846710000 - 0x00007ff846731000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007ff849760000 - 0x00007ff84980a000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ff832a20000 - 0x00007ff832a3e000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x00007ff849540000 - 0x00007ff849681000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ff8476b0000 - 0x00007ff847709000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x00007ff849df0000 - 0x00007ff84a001000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
0x00007ff847750000 - 0x00007ff8478a0000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ff847170000 - 0x00007ff847185000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
0x00007ff845220000 - 0x00007ff8452d2000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.dll
0x00007ff847710000 - 0x00007ff847746000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ff849810000 - 0x00007ff849962000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ff8448c0000 - 0x00007ff844b3a000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.17810_none_6240b9c7ecbd0bda\COMCTL32.dll
0x00000000505e0000 - 0x00000000506b2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000076c90000 - 0x000000007752a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ff83c9a0000 - 0x00007ff83c9a9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ff844140000 - 0x00007ff844162000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ff83fad0000 - 0x00007ff83fada000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ff847900000 - 0x00007ff847907000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ff847a40000 - 0x00007ff847a9a000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ff843cf0000 - 0x00007ff843d1a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ff847c80000 - 0x00007ff847c89000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x00007ff8475a0000 - 0x00007ff8475ef000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007ff845f60000 - 0x00007ff845f88000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x0000000050950000 - 0x000000005095f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000050570000 - 0x0000000050599000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000050550000 - 0x0000000050566000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00000004a4640000 - 0x00000004a465a000     C:\Users\Nicholas1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DemoJNI_Lib\dist\DemoJNI_Lib.dll
0x0000000180040000 - 0x0000000180610000     C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
0x00007ff83ca70000 - 0x00007ff83cbf9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Nicholas1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DemoJNI_Lib\dist\ 
java_command: demojni.Main
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\Nicholas1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DemoJNI_Lib\dist;C:\Users\Nicholas1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DemoJNI\build\classes
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\SN Systems\PS3\bin;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\%M2_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Users\Nicholas1\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\FAHClient
USERNAME=Nicholas1
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 8.1 , 64 bit Build 9600 (6.3.9600.17415)

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 69 stepping 1, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2

Memory: 4k page, physical 4096180k(552828k free), swap 9339060k(3424740k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_111-b14), built on Sep 22 2016 19:24:05 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Sun Apr 09 21:29:25 2017
elapsed time: 27 seconds (0d 0h 0m 27s)
```

The Following are my Steps I followed for Compilation, Linking and Running:

Creating/Compilation Header file:

```
1.  Open cmd prompt in “C:\Users\Nicholas1\Documents\NetBeansProjects”
2.  Run “javah –o DemoJNI_Lib/DemoJNI_Lib.h –classpath DemoJNI/src demojni.Main”, where;
-   “DemoJNI_Lib” is your C++ dynamic library project.
-   DemoJNI_Lib.h declaration for your Java/C header for the C-class file.
-   DemoJNI is the name of your java project with src folder.
-   demojni is your java project package name
-   Main is your main java file.
```

Build/Linker options for C/C++ Project:

```
1.  Right-click on DemoJNI_Lib project and select properties. Go to Build/C Compiler then look under General/Include Directories and click on directories button(…), then select Add button. Now select the include folder from “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\include”, then select Add button and select the win32 folder from “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\include/win32”, finally choose OK-button.
2.  Right-click on DemoJNI_Lib project and select properties. Go to Build/C-Compiler find “Command Line”/”Additional Options”, then type “-shared –m32”
3.  Right-click on DemoJNI_Lib project and select properties “Build”/”Linker”, find “General”/”Output”, then type dist/DemoJNI_Lib.dll
4.  Optional:Add typedef long long __int64; or #define __int64 long long to top of DemoJNI_Lib.h file. Should be above #include <jni.h>.
5.  Build .dll library file: in Netbeans find C/C++ project with c-file and header-file, then Project->(right click)->Clean and Build.
```

Running Java file:

```
1.  In Netbeans Select DemoJNI java project, Main.java->(Right-click)->Run
```

Comment: Please Share yours Steps you had followed for Compilation, Linking and Running.

Comment: Thank you Sumeet for your timely response to my youtube comment. I updated my original question with the Compilation, Linking and Running of my JNI project.

Comment: Thanks give me some time i'll check

Comment: It seems you have all steps related to NetBeans. Did you tried created with my approach ? Give a try at least we will come to know that things are working with you or not.

Comment: I followed your steps so far in your video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDhOPYi-rYE&spfreload=1 , so far I have the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools and also the file "vsvars32.bat". The 'cls' command load the command prompt. But I get error 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I normally use gcc to compile my dll-library, do I need to configure my microsoft visual stuidos to get the 'cl' command to work?

Comment: Yes.. GCC will work for Linux. Use Visual Studio will create exactly what you want. use GCC for .so files

Comment: Sin 'cl' is not recognized as internal or external command, What is missing from Microsoft visual Studios that I can add?

Comment: Since 'cl' is not recognized as internal or external command, What is missing from Microsoft visual Studios that I can add?

Comment: its available https://youtu.be/tDhOPYi-rYE?t=253 under **vsvars32.bat** , please check do you have that bat file with you or not

Comment: Just got the "cl" command working, just need to run "cl" after running the "vsvars32.bat" and "cls" command

Comment: Hey Wero and Sumeet, I just got the "Factorial.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform" error. How can I build a 64-bit dll with microsoft visual studios or with gcc comiler?

Comment: Sumeet! Just got your tutorial to work! I used this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24009338/3576562 to find the solution to the "Factorial.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform" error. I had to use the 64-bit compiler from Microsoft Visual Studios. I used file "vcvars64.bat" found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64 .

Comment: I think the error with Netbeans is with the cygwin compiler that it uses to build the dll. For some reason the dll crashes when it runs native C-code. What do you think?

Comment: @ComputerScience Happy to help you :) since there is no 64bit solution available with tutorial, i'll try to put audio as well as 64bit Solution.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure the 64bit tutorial will help someone!

Comment: Sumeet Thanks for accepting the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not figured out the exact solution to the crash error with the Cygwin C/C++ Compiler, But the alternative solution to this error is to use the Microsoft Visual Studios C/C++ Compiler.

Here's a link to a JNI solution that uses the Microsoft Visual Studios C/C++ Compiler: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDhOPYi-rYE&spfreload=1

Note: If you use Microsoft Visual Studios C/C++ Compiler for JNI development,

- For a 32-bit dll use "vsvars32.bat" found at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools".
- For my setup I needed a 64-bit dll file so I used "vcvars64.bat" found at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64"

Answer (score 0):

I also countered this issue after update of java 8 on win64 system. 
If we see the log you will find "windows-amd64" which I don't know why ?
I followed following steps to get rid of this issue.
1. Remove JAVA 8 update from Add - Remove programs 
2. delete contains of the temp directory
3. Restart the PC.
4. Update the java 8 now.
 
5. Check the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\lib` it should not show folder "windows-amd64".
6. Check the server now.

Hope this helps.