# I don't have SetEnv.cmd in Microsoft SDK

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to do some fix so for Python PIP issues, I found out in :
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473854/python-pip-has-issues-with-path-for-ms-visual-studio-2010-express-for-64-bit-ins)

but when I tried to locate :
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd

I could not find it.

thanks.

Comment: the v7.1 SDK directory is there?

Comment: Yes, this is what I have :  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A

Comment: You say you have `v7.1A`, but your question says you're looking in `v7.1`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find Windows SDK's SetEnv.cmd / SetEnv.cmd Does not work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887894/how-to-find-windows-sdks-setenv-cmd-setenv-cmd-does-not-work-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You need to type the "setenv \64" (for example if you want to set environment for x64)  on the Windows SDKv7.1 command prompt.

Go ->  All Programs > Windows SDKv7.1 > Windows SDKv7.1 Comman prompt >
then type >setenv \x64 (or whatever you want to install)